# how to use svm for character recognition in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, ocr, svm, matlab-cvst

I have a set of characters and numbers in JPEG format. I want to use SVM to classify the images.

my question is to classify the characters not recognize the characters in image.

eg: I have characters from 1 to 10 and a to z, if my input image is a number 6, it should give the output as 6 or belongs to class numbers

I don't know how to start.
 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Digit Classification Using HOG Features](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html) example in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  It uses the SVM classifier and does  exactly what you need.